# How to change Content-Type: appication/x-www-form-urlencoded to application/json?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to make a user registration express. I made the backend first and it seems to work fine since I verified it using postman. In postman, I included Content-Type as application/json, and json data in a raw data tab. However, I could not implement this back-end to the front-end when making a form (name,email,password). I got errors to include name, email, and password even though I did. I tried to console.log the req.body and got empty array. However, in the network tab in Chrome, name, email and password are included in the Form-Data and. I don't think the problem was with body-parser since there was no any problem in postman. In the network tab, I saw that the the Content-Type of the req was `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead of `application/json`, I think this might be the cause of the error.

server.js

```
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
app.get('/register', (req, res) => res.render('register'));
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/api/users'));
```

api/users.js

```
// @ route    POST api/users
// @desc      Register User
// @access    Public
router.post(
  '/',
  [
    check('name', 'Name is required')
      .not()
      .isEmpty(),
    check('email', 'Please include a valid email').isEmail(),
    check(
      'password',
      ' Please enter a password with 6 or more characters'
    ).isLength({ min: 6 })
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      console.log(req.body);
      return res.status(400).json({
        errors: errors.array()
      });
    }
    const { name, email, password } = req.body;
.
.
.
```

register.handlebars

```
  <form class="form" action="/api/users" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Name" requried>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="E-mail">
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input name="password" type="text" placeholder="Password" minlength="6">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Create account" class="button green-button" />
            </form>
```

Comment: Despite the fact that it works in Postman, I'm still not sure if you're using the body parser correctly. Try to remove `app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));` and add the following instead `const bodyParser = require('body-parser'); app.use(bodyParser.json()); app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`. Sorry for that one-liner, but I'm not sure if that can be considered an answer yet, so I can't format the code here.

Comment: oh it worked! Could you explain why? what's the difference between a request from postman and from a browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`express.json()` is a parser for data with `Content-Type: application/json`. You're using it in your code, that's why it works in Postman. In order to parse data encoded as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, you simply need to add another parser, which in this case is `express.urlencoded()`. Also, the `extended` option is accepted by `urlencoded()`, not by `json()`.

```
app.use(express.json()) // parses application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // parses application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```